# Problem when executing the bubblewrap build command

Tags: apk, progressive-web-apps, google-play-console, bubblewrap

I'm trying to convert my website to a PWA (which I already have done). However, in order to upload it to a platform like Google Play, I need the apk. To do this, I have followed the steps recommended by Google itself, which is through the console application called bubblewrap.

When I get to the last step, which is to execute the command:

`bubblewrap build`

I get the following error:

```
Building the Android App...


cli ERROR Command failed: gradlew.bat assembleRelease --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Users\maria\.bubblewrap\jdk\jdk-11.0.9.1+1\bin\java.exe --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx1536m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=ES -Duser.language=es -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\maria\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Users\maria\.bubblewrap\jdk\jdk-11.0.9.1+1\bin\java.exe --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx1536m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=ES -Duser.language=es -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\maria\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:176)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:137)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.doStartDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:217)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:211)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:133)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:145)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:99)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:294)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:266)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:259)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

How could I solve it? I have already tried updating the Java JDK, reverting to an earlier version like Java 8, and updating Gradle, but I can't seem to resolve anything.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you give more details as your gradle config ?